# Can someone help me to find this song? Background music of “Lipstick Prince” korean show

Tags: identify-this-song, lyrics, soundtrack, song-title

can someone help me to find a Korean song? The song is a background music for “Prince Lipstick Season 2 and Episode 6 (Part 2 in minute 27:12) ON Daily Motion. which is Pentagon and Hyuna as a guest. The song im looking for is during Rowoon SF9 put bracelet on Hyuna.  I really hope someone could help me find the song..  thank you

Answer (score 2):

[Here it is](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fAWuUGamXME)!: It seems to be translated to 'Creating Love'. It seems to be a soundtrack for something in Korean, I assume from the TV show. I do not read nor speak Korean, so there is not much more information I could find outside of this:

Title: 사랑 만들기

Album: 韩国M-net单曲榜13

Release date: 2010-04-21

Comment: Hai.. Thank you so much ya.. i really love the song. I appreciate your effort too . Thanks again

Comment: @Anastasia andra I'm glad I could help out! Accept my answer please if it is sufficient